# Why can't I create a Permissions Level?

Tags: permissions

I'd like to create a custom Permission Level, or edit one, but I'm not presented with options to. According to the help documentation, I should see an "Add Permission Level" button or something similar but none is available. Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Here's what I'm seeing:]

I'm listed as having full permissions for the site, and the site is not inheriting permissions from the parent site.
Why can't I change the Permission Levels that are already there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add Permission level at **the top level site** , So Make sure that you are now on the root site collection >

- Go to site Setings> Users and Permissions  > Site permissions > From the above ribbon you > click on permission level

You should now see `Add a Permission Level`

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I was expecting. Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 6):

The permission roles emanate from the root site of the collection. That is the only place where you can create and customize permission levels. They then trickle down as being available in subsites. If you do not have permission to do so in the root of the site collection, you'll need to have someone do it for you.

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I was expecting. Thanks for the confirmation!